# How to present one namespace model with grape-entity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-grape, grape-api

I have one namespace model like this :

```
class Message::Notification < Message
end
```

And I define one entity like this:

```
class Message::Notification < Grape::Entity
   expose :id
end
```

There is a error when present the model:

```
    present @notification, with: Entities::Message::Notification
```

Error:

> app/models/message/notification.rb:1:in `': superclass
>   mismatch for class Notification (TypeError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining the same class with a different superclass. It looks to me like your second definition should be in a module Entities.